# setting up zone file for coredns

Tags: coredns, bind9

I created a zone file named db.example.home

```
$ORIGIN example.home.
@   3600 IN SOA sns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. (
                2017042746 ; serial
                7200       ; refresh (2 hours)
                3600       ; retry (1 hour)
                1209600    ; expire (2 weeks)
                3600       ; minimum (1 hour)
                )

    3600 IN NS a.iana-servers.net.
    3600 IN NS b.iana-servers.net.

www     IN A     127.0.0.1
        IN AAAA  ::1
```

in the log I see

```
2020-08-22T15:16:02.961383295Z [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = fe10aca860b9e9cf7988937438619317
,2020-08-22T15:23:02.960503545Z [ERROR] plugin/file: Failed to open zone "example.home." in "db.example.home": open db.example.home: no such file or directory
```

even though my db.example.home is in the same location as configuration file.

my coredns configuration file looks like this:

```
.:53 {
  forward . tls://192.168.5.238 tls://1.1.1.1 {
    tls_servername cloudflare-dns.com
    health_check 10s
  }
  log
  errors
  cache
  prometheus :9153
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
}

example.org {
    file db.example.org
    log
}
```

I hope someone can through some light what is going wrong here..

Comment: It looks like that config file doesn't match your error message. The config file specifies "db.example.org" as the file to load, but the error message says "db.example.home" is missing?

Comment: You may also need to specify the absolute path, in addition to the message above. Another possible issue is permissions..._maybe_. If you have a `coredns` user, make sure the files you're trying to access aren't owned by `root`.